# To many connections | Temporary failure in name resolution (AWS, EC2, Aurora mySQL)

Tags: mysql, laravel, aws, ec2

Tengo un par de errores que se presentan mi proyecto de Laravel. Anteriormente estaba todo montado en Google Cloud, después se decidió por migrar a AWS.

En Google Cloud nunca tuvo errores de este tipo.

Pero en AWS, da estos tipos de errores, de vez en cuando.

Después el sitio se queda inaccesible, reinicio la instancia de EC2 (aunque el problema fue de base de datos) y vuelve a ser accesible el sitio.

Los errores, tomados desde los logs de Laravel:

```
[2022-07-31 08:41:04] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections (SQL: valid SQL query) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1040): SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections (SQL: valid SQL query) at /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)


[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for MY_DB_HOST_AWS_AURORA failed: Temporary failure in name resolution at /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40)
```

Una vez que reinicio la instancia toma un uno o dos de días para que el error vuelva a salir y truene todo.

Hasta ahora no tengo ninguna idea de qué es lo que está provocando estos errores.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es de configuración de tus instancias de BD en Aurora.

[Este enlace](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-max-connection-errors/) sugiere dos tareas principales:

- Revisar las conexiones activas al momento del error y, si es posible, terminarlas.
- Aumentar el número máximo de conexiones para su instancia de BD.

Para lo primero, se pueden usar cosas como

```
CALL mysql.rds_kill(thread-ID);
CALL mysql.rds_kill_query(thread-ID);
```

Para lo segundo, comienza por revisar cuál es el valor actual del parámetro

`select @@max_connections;`

Luego, hay dos opciones principales:

- [Usar un tipo de instancia más grande](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Changing) (enlace a documentación en inglés)
- Subir el valor para el parámetro `max_connections` usando un grupo de parámetros personalizado (custom) a nivel de instancia [(documentación en inglés)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html).

PD. Vale la pena hacerle tuning de una vez a todos los parámetros y no sólo ese.

PD2. ¿No es como muy caro usar Aurora?